# QT pyside2 querying textfield in maya from .ui file

Tags: python, qt, maya

I am trying to create a ui with a textfield input, that I then want to query and return to a variable in maya when the button is pressed.

I have the .ui file with the textfield named uniqueName, but I can't seem to get it to even print the text from that textfield.

I am not sure if I got the loading of the .ui wrong or if I am missing the correct way of querying the string typed into the ui by the user.

```
filename = "/home/bsorensen/Documents/qt_scripts/rigbox_0_01.ui"
def __init__(self):
    ui = filename
    MayaMain = shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(MayaUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()), QtWidgets.QWidget)
    super(MainUI, self).__init__(MayaMain)
    loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
    self.UI = loader.load(filename)
    self.UI.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)  
    self.UI.destroyed.connect(self.onExitCode)
    self.UI.setWindowTitle('Rigbox')         
    self.UI.show()
    self.UI.armsTemp.clicked.connect(self._doArms)


def onExitCode(self):
    #Do this when the script is closed
    sys.stdout.write("You closed rigbox.\n")


def _getUniqueName(self):
    # Reading Unique string widget
    # get string value
    self.uniqueNameString = self.uniqueName.toPlainText()
    return str(self.uniqueNameString)

def _doArms(self):
    navn = self._getUniqueName()
    print navn

def run():
    MainUI()
```

Comment: do you have some error ? could it be just : self.UI.uniqueName ?

Comment: change to `self.UI.uniqueName.toPlainText()`